# How to populate fields in a has_many through join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

I have a question concerning active record association, referring to this part of the rails documentation:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association

if we have three models:

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, :through => :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, :through => :appointments
end
```

The documentation says that the collection of join models can be managed via the api this way:

```
physician.patients = patients
```

but what if the appointment model, like in the linked example, has a field called appointment_date and I want to create a new appointment given the Physician and the Patient at a specific date?
The following code will create a record in the appointment table, but how to populate the appointment_date too in the third step?

```
physician = Physician.first
patient = Patients.first
physician.patients << patient
```

does something like this exists?

```
physician.patients.create( :patient => patient, 'appointment.appointment_time' => appointment_time )
```

Comment: I'm also running into this issue... I want to change a default value on an attribute in the join table, but only when an associated record is created (for example, if a Patient is created, set the appointment time, but in other situations we'd just make new appointments).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

old question, but it should be answered - although you can assign directly to `physician.patients` with the `<<` method, it creates an appointment with no values, which may or may not be valid depending on the business rules. So the more usual way to create the association would be to build the appointment on one of them

```
demento = Physician.find_by_name('Dr. Demento'}
patient = Patient.new { :name => 'Mrs. Holloway' }
patient.appointments << Appointment.new { :physician => demento, :appointment_time => appt_time }
```

you could combine lines 2 and 3 of course if you are so inclined.

the line in the docs you refer to

```
physician.patients = patients
```

I think the narrow use case for that might be, if Demento had 7 patients but loses Mrs. Holloway due to an unfortunate incident with a death ray experiment, then you could do this with a updated list of the 6 extant patients and their appointments would be preserved, and Mrs. Holloway's past appointments would be automatically deleted (so as to erase any record of here, for liability insurance reasons? only Demento would be so dastardly).

Comment: upvote for the explanation including the phrase 'death ray experiment'

Answer (score 2):

You wish to consider nested routes, e.g.

```
resources :physicians do
  resource :patients
end
```

The you can use things like `form_for(@physician, @patient)`

and url's like `physician/1/patient/23`

for updating a patient within the context of a physician.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but that's not exactly what I'm looking for