# Setting and reading has_many :through join table data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's take the example from the [association documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html):

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end
```

My question is, supposing the `Appointment` model has an `appointment_date` field how can I set it most elegantly when working with new physicians and patients?

For now my solution for creation is, that **instead** of using:

```
physician = Physician.new(...)
patient = Patient.new(...)
physician.patients < patient
physician.save
```

I use:

```
physician = Physician.new(...)
patient = Patient.new(...)
appointment = Appointment.new
appointment.physician = physician
appointment.patient = patient
appointment.appointment_date = Time.now
appointment.save
```

And for querying I found the [following solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874702/need-data-from-rails-join-table-has-many-through).

Is there a shorter / more succinct / "Rails" way?

Comment: In the meantime I also found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11039314/179570).

Comment: do you want any more refactor?

Comment: What do you mean? I detailed what I want as best as I could in the question itself.

Comment: I think the solutions you found are "Rails" ways, `patient.appointments.create(appointment_date: Time.now, physician: physician)` may be a little more, but it is almost the same:) The next step is encapsulate the logic in the model, and make the call in one line, it's a personal option.....