# How to create has_many :through associations with presence validations using Rails 4, seeds.rb, and the console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using a `has_many :through` association between a `Musician` and an `Instrument` through a `MusiciansInstrument` join table:

```
class Musician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :musicians_instruments
  has_many :instruments, through: :musicians_instruments
end

class Instrument < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :musicians_instruments
  has_many :musicians, through: :musicians_instruments
  validates :instrument_name, presence: true
end

class MusiciansInstrument < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :musician
  belongs_to :instrument 
  validate :began_playing, presence: true
end
```

I want to make sure that I know how many years each `Musician` has been playing each `Instrument`, so I have a required `began_playing` datetime field in my `MusiciansInstrument` table.

I would like to do this without `accepts_nested_attributes_for` if possible.

My `schema.rb`(minus timestamps):

```
create_table "musicians_instruments", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "musician_id"
  t.integer  "instrument_id"
  t.datetime "began_playing"
end

create_table "instruments", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "instrument_name"
end

create_table "musicians", force: true do |t|
end
```

My question is what is how to best create objects using this association when making seeds and querying objects in the console.  I also need to get FactoryGirl making these, but first things first.

1) In the console (using the approach proposed in [this Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164865/how-to-populate-fields-in-a-has-many-through-join-table))

```
musician = Musician.new 
#=> #<Musician id: nil, user_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
instrument = Instrument.new(:instrument_name => 'Bass Guitar') 
#=> #<Instrument id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, instrument_name: "Bass Guitar"> 
instrument.save!
musician.musicians_instruments << MusiciansInstrument.create(:instrument => instrument, :began_playing => Time.now - 10.years)
#=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<MusiciansInstrument id: 19, musician_id: nil, instrument_id: 15, began_playing: "2004-02-25 23:52:12">]>
musician.save! 
#=> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Instruments can't be blank
```

2) In seeds.rb:

```
m7 = Musician.create
i7 = Instrument.create(:instrument_name => 'Voice')
m7.musicians_instruments << MusiciansInstrument.create(:instrument => i7, :began_playing => Time.now - 10.years)
```

These console queries return:

```
Musician.includes(:instruments).where(instruments.instrument_name => "Voice") #=>NameError: undefined local variable or method `instruments' for main:Object

Musician.joins(:instruments).where(instruments.instrument_name => "Voice") #=>NameError: undefined local variable or method `instruments' for main:Object
```

---

The seeds.rb statements work, and do create the associated objects and populate the through table with a `began_playing` date, but the queries are wrong.  Two ways to query the `began_playing` field on the has_many :through join table are:

```
MusiciansInstrument.joins(:musician).where.not(began_playing: nil) 
#=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<MusiciansInstrument id: 13, musician_id: 7, instrument_id: 7, began_playing: "1984-02-26 03:59:01">]> 

MusiciansInstrument.joins(:instrument).where.not(began_playing: nil) 
#=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<MusiciansInstrument id: 13, musician_id: 7, instrument_id: 7, created_at: "2014-02-26 03:59:01", updated_at: "2014-02-26 03:59:01", began_playing: "1984-02-26 03:59:01">]>
```

Does anyone know how or if this could be queried from the `Musician` or `Instrument` objects?  Something like this, which doesn't work:

```
Musician.joins(:musicians_instruments).where.not(:musicians_instruments.began_playing => nil)
```

Comment: Man, this is ONLY timestamps :P

Comment: In your 1), you don't yet have a musician ID and you get an exception with musician.save!. You must save musician before create the association.

Comment: Thanks, beginner's mistake.  I had been using has_and_belongs_to_many with the validation constraint on the Musician requiring an Instrument, and had gotten used to not being able to create a Musician without first giving it an Instrument.  When I switched to has_many :through that became a fatal habit.  That answers #1, and if you post your comment as an answer, I will mark it up.  I still get the same error with #2, even using create to make a Musician, but my query is probably wrong, so I can't tell if my seeds.rb made a good association or not.

Comment: That's ok. In number 2, it's the same idea.

Comment: Actually, all the `MusiciansInstrument` instances created by `seeds.rb` look like this, `#<MusiciansInstrument id: 10, musician_id: 4, instrument_id: 1, created_at: "2014-02-26 01:10:35", updated_at: "2014-02-26 01:10:35", began_playing: nil>`.  All have nil for `began_playing`.  So #2 is still in the wind....  Plus the queries about still throw `NameError`.

Comment: Maybe your syntax should be more like Musician.joins(:instruments).where(instruments: {instrument_name: "Voice"})

Comment: Thanks, that works and adds to my understanding of how to query joins!